# How to test the type of an Objective-c Object ? something similar to is with Object?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How to test the type of an **Objective-c Object** ? something similar to `is` with TObject? To cast we have `wrap` but I don't find how to test

Comment: `OCClass` property should give you the class type. So something like `if MyObj.OCClass is NSSomeClass then` might work.

Comment: Most likely use object_getClass from Macapi.ObjCRuntime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remembered that I'm actually using object_getClass in my own code :-)

This is an example from [DW.Notifications.iOS.pas](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/blob/master/Features/Notifications/DW.Notifications.iOS.pas) :

```
if request.trigger.isKindOfClass(objc_getClass('UNPushNotificationTrigger')) then
```