# How to do IS with an objective C class?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delphi, firemonkey

I try to convert this ios/objective-c function under delphi Rio 10.3.3

```
func authorizationController(authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential { 

    } else if let passwordCredential = authorization.credential as? ASPasswordCredential {

    }
}
```

I set `authorization.credential` to be a `pointer`. Now my problem how with this pointer can I check the IS  `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential` before to cast like for example :

```
if authorization.credential IS ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential then 
  TASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential.wrap(authorization.credential);
```

Comment: Already asked (by you) and answered (by me) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59122544/3164070

Comment: @DaveNottage I become old :( :( :( thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the isKindOfClass: selector that is in NSobject. In your case

```
if([authorization.credential isKindOfClass:[AsAuthorizationAppleIDCredential class]])
{ // is that class }
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418511-iskindofclass?language=objc

EDIT: If you want to only perform one selector on the object you could also check if it performs that selector with respondsToSelector: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418583-respondstoselector?language=objc